# Retrieving parent img value jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck on this seemingly easy problem. I'm trying to change the parent image of my product item upon change is detected in the options.

```js
$('#colors').change(function () {
    var img_path = './img/' + $('#colors',this).find('.item-image').val() + $(this).val().toLowerCase()     +'.jpg';
    console.log(img_path)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, I kept getting unidentified appended to the path string and it's driving me crazy.

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<article class="product-area">
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <img class="item-image" value="test" src="img/item-body-1.png" alt="">
      <h1 class="item-title">Aluminum road bike</h1>
      <h4 class="sub-item-heading">Customisation:</h4>
      <table class="customization-table">
        <tr>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Material</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="colors" name="colors">
              <option data-color="Default">Default</option>
              <option data-color="Red">Red</option>
              <option data-color="Blue">Blue</option>
              <option data-color="Green">Green</option>
              <option data-color="Brown">Brown</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="materials" name="materials">
              <option data-material="Alloy">Alloy</option>
              <option data-material="Steel">Steel</option>
              <option data-material="Carbon Fibre">Carbon Fibre</option>
              <option data-material="Titanium">Titanium</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="button-group">
        <button class="add-to-cart" data-name="Aluminum road bike " data-price="256">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get attr() value and target parent block, to find image.

val() method works for form fields, not for the rest of the elements.

```js
$('#colors').change(function () {
    var img_path = './img/' + $('.product-area').find('.item-image').attr('value') + $(this).val().toLowerCase()     +'.jpg';
    console.log(img_path)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="product-area">
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <img class="item-image" value="test" src="img/item-body-1.png" alt="">
      <h1 class="item-title">Aluminum road bike</h1>
      <h4 class="sub-item-heading">Customisation:</h4>
      <table class="customization-table">
        <tr>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Material</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="colors" name="colors">
              <option data-color="Default">Default</option>
              <option data-color="Red">Red</option>
              <option data-color="Blue">Blue</option>
              <option data-color="Green">Green</option>
              <option data-color="Brown">Brown</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="materials" name="materials">
              <option data-material="Alloy">Alloy</option>
              <option data-material="Steel">Steel</option>
              <option data-material="Carbon Fibre">Carbon Fibre</option>
              <option data-material="Titanium">Titanium</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="button-group">
        <button class="add-to-cart" data-name="Aluminum road bike " data-price="256">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

P.S. If multiple blocks with same parent class are on page, use closest():

```
   var img_path = './img/' + $(this).closest('.product-area').find('.item-image').attr('value')...
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, also thank you very much for the $(this)closest part, that was my next question :)